# Updating Parse.com and alert view errors

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to make that way that when user sign up he/she does not have `firstname` and `lastname`. Then, error shows that data is nil because I have coded that when user will login his user details should show in left side menu but that can only be added by clicking on update button.

If a person is already logged in and it works. I want that person sign up and it does not show them the details and when person opens it and edit his profile and then update it then it should show.

in `leftsidemenuViewcontroller.swift`

```
func loadUserDetails() {


    let userFirstName = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("first_name") as! String
    let userLastName = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("last_name") as! String
    FullnameLabel.text = userFirstName + " " + userLastName


    let ProfilePictureObject =  PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("Profile_Image") as! PFFile

    ProfilePictureObject.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (ImageData: NSData?, Error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if(ImageData != nil) {
                self.profileimage.image = UIImage(data: ImageData!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn your conditions besides the first and the last to be else if statements, that way, only one condition will execute. Currently, your else statement finds a matching if statement which actually is the one right before it, rather than the first one you wrote. Therefore, the saving of your object is only rejected if the passwords do not match.

So it should look like

```
if(){

}
else if(){


}
else if(){

}
else{

}
```

Comment: i want it all the conditions to pass

Comment: Awesome glad I could help

Comment: can you help me in one more problem @josh Hamet

Comment: What can I do for you

Comment: hey i actually i made a edit profile button in which we can update our profile like new profile pictyre,adding a firstname,lastname so its working fine but the problem is when a person makes a new signup then where the these data display shows error that there is no data. I understand my mistake what i want is that when person signups and then can update its profile if you need code i can send you

Comment: i have a left side menu in which all the details are displayed because of signup(i dont have firstname and lastname field) thats why its showing me error

Comment: Some code would prolly help me understand your mistake better

Comment: I guess it will be very difficult to understand to you

Comment: How about if there's no first and last name , display an empty string and allow them to edit it and then you can save all the updates fields

Comment: Yup this is what i want

Comment: so tell me how we will do it ?@josh Hamet

Comment: Well check if the first name field returns an object , if so set the text field as its contents , if it's null, set the field as empty .